# Can anyone recommend an Android text pre-fill library

Tags: android, textinput

I'm looking for a library that does something similar to what the input field in Google's search input does.  I know it's a long shot, but thought perhaps it's part of the SDK and I'm overlooking it, or someone has written a handy lib.

The only difference between the google text hinting and what I want, is that I want to be able to add my own strings to the hints... the practical application here is that I have a huge list of company names and I want to help the users type them in (cause many of them are fairly long)...

I have a pretty good idea of how to write this myself if I absolutely have to, but was hoping that someone's already done the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it exists.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html
AutoCompleteTextView